# how to translate day in laravel use carbon

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm editing a script to customize the day into Indonesian, how do I translate it in carbon getdays?

this is the script contained in app/Support/Date.php

```
 public static function dayFromInt($num)
{
    return Arr::get(Carbon::getDays(), $num);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't make Carbon::getDates() work with different locale, but it just returns an array of the days of the week, so you can change the function like:

```
public static function dayFromInt($num)
{
    //change with values in your language
    $weekdays = [
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    ];
    return Arr::get($weekdays, $num);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Carbon::setlocale('id-ID');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set the timezone in `config/app.php`, like

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

And then use laravel illuminate carbon instead of `Carbon\Carbon`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

Then laravel automatically translate carbon values into Kolkata timezone in everywhere you use carbon

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function dayFromInt($num)
{
    return Carbon::parse('Sunday')
        ->addDays($num)
        ->locale('id_ID')
        ->dayName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
...
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

```
public function __construct()
{
   Carbon::setlocale('id');
}
```

here is the languages list you can use in carbon localization

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/List/languages.php